# The right way to set z-index

Tags: css, z-index, shadow

I have that html

```
<div id="menu">
    <a class="active"></a>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

And that css

```
#menu {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}

#content {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    text-shadow: -10px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.23),0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.16);
}

#menu a.active:after {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    text-shadow: -10px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.23),0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.16);
}
```

I want a.active:after was above then #content so that the shadow does not dropped on the a.active:after. How i can do this?

Comment: Show us the demo what you tried sofar?

Comment: @Etash look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mur1bzkp/) I want nice arrow, but #content shadow...

Comment: @Etash I mean, want to arrow merge with the background of #content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mur1bzkp/2/)**

I removed box shadow from #content and added to #menu as inner shadow.

**CSS:**

```
#menu {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:7;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    background:green;
    box-shadow:inset -10px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .23), inset 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
    overflow:hidden;
}
#menu a.active {
    padding:5px;
    background:#fff;
    display:block;
    margin-top:20px;
    z-index:9;
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:yellow;
    left:200px;
}
#menu a.active:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: yellow;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    /* Prefixes... */
    top: 21px;
    right: -11px;
    box-shadow: -10px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .23), 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
}
```